# Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: support, openid, yahoo

I don't know if this is an issue with StackOverflow, Yahoo or someone in between, but I'm seeing a lot of failures to login using Yahoo as an OpenID provider.  If you keep trying, eventually it will work (after maybe 6-8 goes?).

Other OpenID providers seem to work straight away.

This has very much the same symptoms as this question, which was closed a couple of months ago, so the solution may be the same.

- [Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51940/unable-to-log-in-with-your-openid-provider-no-openid-endpoint-found)

[image: Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found.]

Comment: +1 for a green Freehand Circle

Comment: I have this problem logging in to SE sites so often, it's not even funny.

Comment: I don't have much of a problem with this on my PC, but when i try to log in on my mobile, I have that problem...I use Yahoo.

Comment: In the last month or so, I've been having this problem intermittently  from multiple computers on multiple networks. If I keep trying, I eventually get signed in. I use myOpenID.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a rule to include the [OpenID troubleshooting tips link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips) in every question related to this.

Comment: Yahoo is known to have server farm issues from time to time..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: mine is a delegate through myOpenID.

Comment: Update: I noted in [another answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64244/openid-endpoint-suddenly-not-found/70508#70508) that I've been having DNS issues.